# Upload ASP.NET project to web

Tags: asp.net, web, upload

I created a ASP.NET project (without database) and now I want to upload it to the web.
I found a hosting server (x10hosting) and I published my problem through FTP to the server.
The problem accures when I'm tring to navigate into my website - all I get is tree of the elements that are in my project (aspx pages, bin folder, etc) and even when I'm clicking on one of the pages I just see the code I wrote.

If someone could explain how to upload ASP.NET project to the web that would be great :)
Thanks alot!

Comment: that means the web server is treating aspx files as text file and not actually recognizing it! does that web hosting supports asp.net or just PHP ?

Comment: You need to have asp.net registered on IIS, so that it understands the ASPX requests. Plus its better to disable directory browsing of the webserver.

Answer (score 2):

To host asp .net web application/website you need to select any asp .net hosting provider. I don't think x10hosting is providing asp .net hosting service, they are facilitating php hosting in free account . You can try to other free hosting site like https://somee.com/default.aspx.